# Output Clusters Correctly - Python

Tags: python, arrays, cluster-analysis, plotly-dash

So, I'm trying to visualize clusters and points in Dash, but a side-function is giving me trouble. Instead of giving me *all* the clusters and sets of points I'm only getting the first of each dimension. And I *know* it must be an essential beginners mistake, but my brain refuses to get out of that hole it dug itself.

So, what am I doing wrong here?

```
def make_dataset(data, clusters):
# Check if there are clusters to plot
if len(clusters) <= 0:
    return

ndim = data.shape[1] #number of features
nrecords = data.shape[0] #data points
data_extent = [[min(data[:, x]), max(data[:, x])] for x in range(0, ndim)]

# Plot clusters in each dimension
for dim in range(1, ndim + 1):
    # Get all clusters in 'dim' dimension(s)
    clusters_in_dim = []
    for c in clusters:
        if len(c.dimensions) == dim:
            clusters_in_dim.append(c)

    # Check if there are clusters in 'dim' dimension(s)
    dim_nclusters = len(clusters_in_dim)
    if dim_nclusters <= 0:
        continue

    # Plot all data points as black points
    if dim == 1:
        xnoise = data[:, 0] #label = noise
        ynoise = [0] * nrecords #label = noise
        ptx1 = [0] * nrecords
        pty1 = data[:, 1]

    elif dim == 2:
        ptx2 = data[:, 0] #label = noise
        pty2 = data[:, 1] #label = noise

    # For all clusters in 'dim' dimension(s)
    for i, c in enumerate(clusters_in_dim):
        c_size = len(c.data_point_ids)
        c_attrs = list(c.dimensions)
        c_elems = list(c.data_point_ids)

        if dim == 1:  # one-dimensional clusters
            cx1 = data[c_elems, 0] if c_attrs[0] == 0 else [0] * c_size
            cy1 = data[c_elems, 1] if c_attrs[0] == 1 else [0] * c_size

        elif dim == 2:  # two-dimensional clusters
            cx2 = data[c_elems, c_attrs[0]]
            cy2 = data[c_elems, c_attrs[1]]

return xnoise, ynoise, ptx1, pty1, ptx2, pty2, cx1, cy1, cx2, cy2
```

my hunch is to save the x and y variables as arrays, but would I be iterating through them like:

```
    for x in range(len(clusters)):
    ptx1.append(clusters[x])
```

does that even make sense? would sets or lists be better for this, as I have to be able to access each cluster separately for the visualization

Answer (score 1):

You are *overwriting* your variables.

So only the last value is returned.